# OpenGL Draw Vertex Buffer Object

Tags: c++, opengl, indexing, vbo

I have two 'std::vector's, one for indices and one for vertices, which I fill with std::vector.push_back().  Then I do

```
glGenBuffers(1, &verticesbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, /*EDITED-->*/vertices.size() * sizeof(vertices[0])/*<--EDITED*/, &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

to create the buffers for each, and then attempt to draw the polygon with

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesbuffer);

glDrawElements(
    GL_TRIANGLES,
    indices.size(),
    GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
    &indices[0]
    );

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

When I run the program, nothing shows up.  I can get it to work using the glBegin() / glEnd() approach but the indexed vbo just doesn't work (glGetError() also doesn't give any errors). I don't even know if this is remotely close to correct as I have searched through countless tutorials and other stackoverflow questions and tried many different things to fix it. I should also mention that I called

```
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glOrtho(0.0f, windowX, windowY, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1000.0f);
```

at the beginning of the program, which I also have no idea if this is correct (as you can see, I am pretty new at this stuff).

Comment: Are you sure no glEnable or glEnableClientState is missing?

Comment: I fixed the mistake pointed out by the answers, but I am still not seeing anything. Am I missing a glEnable or glEnableClientState? The OpenGL method calls that I posted in the question are the only ones I have made that are related to the drawing

Comment: The problem with this question now is that you have not provided a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We have addressed the obvious cause of trouble using the code that you provided.  If you want to continue getting help, you ought to post a new question including a MCVE.

Comment: @ArcaneEnforcer: you actually seem to never set the attribute pointers to point into your VBO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand how `sizeof` operator works. It is an operator which is executed at compile-time and returns the size (in bytes) of the specified type or variable.

```
float f;
std::cout << sizeof(f); // prints 4
std::cout << sizeof(float); // prints 4
```

But what happens when we use `sizeof` on a pointer to an array? Let's examine the following case:

```
float array1[50]; // static size array, allocated on the stack
float *array2 = new float[50]; // dynamic size array, allocated on the heap

std::cout << sizeof(array1); // prints 200, which is ok (50*4 == 200)
std::cout << sizeof(array2); // prints out the size of a float pointer, not the array
```

In the first case we use `sizeof` on a static array, which is allocated on the stack. Since the size of *array1* is constant, the compiler knows about it and returns it's actual size in bytes on `sizeof(array1)`.

In the second case we use `sizeof` on a dynamic array which is allocated on the heap. The size of `array2` ideally cannot be known at compile time (otherwise you should use a static array, if fits into the stack), so the compiler knows nothing about the size of the array *array2*, so it returns the **size of the pointer** to our array.

What happens when you use `sizeof` on std::vector?

```
std::vector<float> vec(50);
std::cout << sizeof(vec); // prints out the size of the vector (but it's not 4*50)
```

But if `sizeof(vec)` returns the size of the vector, why doesn't return 4*50? std::vector manages an underlying dynamically allocated array (second case in the previous example), so the compiler don't know anything about the size of that underlying array. That's why it returns the size of the overall encapsulated (hidden) variables of the vector object, including the size of the pointer to the actual array data. If you want the number of elements in your underlying array, you need to use vec.size(). **To get the size of the underlying float array in bytes, just use** `vec.size() * sizeof(float)`.

Fixing your code with the knowledge from above:

```
std::vector<float> vertices;
// ...add vertices with push_back()...
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(float), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

or

```
std::vector<float> vertices;
// ..add vertices with push_back()...
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(vertices[0]), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: In C++11 and up `vertices.data()` will also give you a pointer to the underlying array

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you expected `sizeof(vertices)` to give you the total number of bytes stored in the vector.  However, it only gives the size of the vector object itself, not the dynamic data it contains.

Instead, you should use `vertices.size() * sizeof(vertices[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

In the future you can also use a graphics debugger to help with these issues. Depending on your card you can use AMDs gpu perf studio or nVidia nsight on windows or graphics debugger on Linux. This saves a lot of time and headaches.

If you get your blank screen again. Run your app with the debugger attached and follow the pipeline.

You should see the data fed into the vertex shader and since it was shorter than what you expected it would flag an issue and you could start there.